# Encoding 4 values in a 32-bit integer

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to make a class that will encode 4 values in one 32-bit integer. So far, it saves and outputs all the values without losing anything, but for some reason, in the wrong order.

```
struct encoder {
    uint32_t val;

    encoder(uint32_t _val = 0) : val(_val) {}

    uint32_t first(uint32_t v = 0) {
        if (!v) return (val << (8*3)) >> (8*3);

        val |= v;
    }

    uint32_t second(uint32_t v = 0) {
        if (!v) return (val << (8*2)) >> (8*3);

        encoder _backupval(val);

        val = (val >> (8*1));
        val |= v;
        val = (val << (8*1));
        val |= _backupval.first();
    }

    uint32_t third(uint32_t v = 0) {
        if (!v) return (val << (8*1)) >> (8*3);

        encoder _backupval(val);

        val = (val >> (8*2));
        val |= v;
        //now restore
        val = val << 8;
        val |= _backupval.second();
        val = val << 8;
        val |= _backupval.first();
    }

    uint32_t fourth(uint32_t v = 0) {
        if (!v) return (val << (8*0)) >> (8*3);

        encoder _backupval(val);

        val = (val >> (8*3));
        val |= v;
        //now restore
        val = val << 8;
        val |= _backupval.second();
        val = val << 8;
        val |= _backupval.first();
        val = val << 8;
        val |= _backupval.third();
    }
};

int main() {
    encoder t;
    t.first(6);
    t.second(42);
    t.third(212);
    t.fourth(23);

    cout << "first number: " << t.first()
         << "\nsecond number: " << t.second()
         << "\nthird number: " << t.third()
         << "\nfourth number: " << t.fourth() << endl;

}
```

Note that I am doing this as an exercise, and this program is not going to be used in real programs. So do not suggest alternative ways to do it, and do not point out the flaws (like if the size of the number is more then 256, it will corrupt the other integer, etc.)

Comment: where did you overload the first() second()... ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  It seems like a pretty straightforward problem that the debugger could handle.

Comment: Also you're missing many return statements. Enable additional compiler warnings

Comment: I the interface would be better as a stack anyway!  t.push(6); t.pop();

Comment: Consider overloading the functions to distinguish between setting/getting, instead of relying on the default value. What if I wanted to encode the number 0?

Comment: `union { int iVal; char bVals[4]; }` would be a lot less buggy and only slightly less portable.

Comment: @Roddy: What about `union { uint32_t iVal; uint8_t bVals[4]; }`? This should be most portable for all architectures that support those types.

Comment: "Note that I am doing this as an exercise, and this code is not going to be used in real programs. So do not suggest alternative ways to do this, and do not point out the flaws."                       Yes, missing return statements is a flaw, and `union { int iVal; char bVals[4]; }` is a better alternative way to do this, which I would probably use in real code. But as I stated above, this is only an exercise, to help me learn bit-wise operators!

Comment: @user1507133 - That's why I commented rather than answered. And saying 'Don't point out the flaws' when you've asked a question to find a specific flaw in your code is, well, a little strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mixed the order of functions in `fourth`:

```
uint32_t fourth(uint32_t v = 0) {
    if (!v) return (val << (8*0)) >> (8*3);

    encoder _backupval(val);

    val = (val >> (8*3));
    val |= v;
    //now restore
    val = val << 8;
    val |= _backupval.second();
    val = val << 8;
    val |= _backupval.first();
    val = val << 8;
    val |= _backupval.third();  // this should be called first!
}
```

This will result in the scrambled return values. Simply call `third` first and [it will work](http://ideone.com/V2Y7D):

```
uint32_t fourth(uint32_t v = 0) {
    if (!v) return (val << (8*0)) >> (8*3);

    encoder _backupval(val);

    val = (val >> (8*3));
    val |= v;
    //now restore
    val = val << 8;
    val |= _backupval.third();
    val = val << 8;
    val |= _backupval.second();
    val = val << 8;
    val |= _backupval.first();
}
```